# Теряются абзацы в String HTML

Tags: html

Я в строку записываю несколько значений с абзацами, а в HTML строка выводится без абзацев. Подскажите пожалуйста, можно как-то исправить?

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей. См. Как создать [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте следующий [css стиль](http://htmlbook.ru/css/white-space):

```
white-space: pre;
```

> Текст показывается с учетом всех пробелов и переносов, как они были добавлены разработчиком в коде HTML. Если строка получается слишком длинной и не помещается в окне браузера, то будет добавлена горизонтальная полоса прокрутки.